# Save internal storage of Android videos and audio from a server

Tags: android, audio, video, save, internal-storage

This is the method I use to store images.

```
private String saveImage (Context context, String name, Bitmap image){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File dirImages = cw.getDir(Imagenes, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File myPath = new File(dirImages, name + .png);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, fos);
            fos.flush();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myPath.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

How do I adapt to store audio and video?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet of code:

```
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO = 3;

/** Create a File for saving an image, video or audio */
public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "App");
    // This locat ion works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            android.util.Log.d("log", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ "PhotoTemp" + ".png");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ "VideoTemp" + ".mp4");
    }
    else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "AUD_"+ "AudioTemp" + ".mp3");
    }  
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

And then:

```
File mediaFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO);
if (mediaFile == null) {
    android.util.Log.d("log", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
    return null;
}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
fos.write(data); //where data is byte[]
fos.close();
```

Comment: I do not see how this stores audio and video. Think you should elaborate on photoData.

Comment: :) you are asking how to adapt the code you post for video/audio. The code above is to use after you got the data from the server. Im gonna fix some things in the code to see if it can help to you.

Comment: Well OP should react i think, I'm not the OP. Originally a Bitmap is saved. So OP should better explain what kind of data he has when he wants to save audio and video. And your code assumes the data is in a byte array i think but you did not mention that..

Comment: Ok I change it a little to match what you need. You are right about byte[]. Let me know a little more about how you expect get the data and let's see if I can do something.

Comment: `to match what you need.`. You mean: `to match what he/she/OP needs.`.

Comment: yep, didn't see who was writing the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

While downloding from server which you probably do in chunks in a byte buffer, immediately write every chunk to file